# Comprobar si dos números son iguales en un juego de memoria mental

Tags: python, lista

Tengo dos problemas, necesito cambiar los números por símbolos (`[X]`, `@`,etc) para que el jugador no pueda saber dónde se encuentran los mismos números y no sé qué puedo poner para que la computadora los elimine de la lista si son iguales.

Lo que debe de ver el usuario son las cuatro listas pero en vez de números, deben de ver algo como la parte trasera de las cartas. Ellos sólo pueden escoger dos y si tienen el mismo valor estas desaparecen hasta que las cuatro listas estén vacías.

Código en *Python*:

```
import random
#DATA
B=['E','C','D','T']
E=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
C=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
D=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
T=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13]
#ELSE
Start=input('Press *Enter* to start game!!!')
random.shuffle(E)
random.shuffle(C)
random.shuffle(D)
random.shuffle(T)
#TEXTURE
print('E=',E)
print('C=',C)
print('D=',D)
print('T=',T)
Coordenadas1 = input('Ingrese la lista1:')
Coordenadas2 = input('Ingrese la posicion1:')
Coordenadas3 = input('Ingrese la lista2:')
Coordenadas4 = input('Ingrese la posicion2:')
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Deberias aclarar un poco que es lo que hace tu código o que pretendes conseguir. Un ejemplo con una salida real esperada sería de gran ayuda. Tienes cuatro listas (creo que representando  barajas de cartas) y las desordenas (barajas). Ahora bién , ¿que se supone que hace tu juego?, ¿qué deberia ver el usuario en cada momento del desarrollo de éste? ¿Ocultas una carta, todas?

Comment: Gracias por tu interés; Lo que debe de ver el usuario son las cuatro listas pero en vez de números, deben de ver algo como la parte trasera de las cartas. Ellos solo pueden escoger dos y si tienen el mismo valor estas desaparecen hasta que las cuatro listas estén vacías.

Answer (score 1):

Vamos a ver..

### Mostrar la lista con sus elementos ocultos.

Hay muchas formas de hacer esto, una de ellas es armar una rutina de "ocultamiento" que reciba una lista y devuelva una lista similar en cuanto a longitud pero con '*', alguna variantes de esta idea:

1. Una función tradicional recibe una lista, crea una lista nueva y
   recorre cada elemento de la lista original y por cada uno va
   agregando un '*', al finalizar devolveremos una lista con la misma
   cantidad de elementos pero con '*'

> ```
> def ocultar(lista):
>   nueva_lista = []
>   for e in range(len(lista)):
>     nueva_lista.append('*')
>   return nueva_lista
>
> print('E=',ocultar(E))
> ```

2. Lo anterior, si bien es muy explicativo, resulta un poco largo. Hay
   algunas formas más compactas de hacer lo mismo, por ejemplo usando
   comprensión de listas, una técnica muy interesante del lenguaje

> ```
> def ocultar(lista):
>     return ['*' for e in lista]
>
> print('E=',ocultar(E))
> ```

3. Otra forma incluso más compacta y más rápida es crear una función
   lambda, que es básicamente un forma rápida de crear una función de
   forma temporal y dinámica, y también hacemos uso de la aritmética de
   listas, dónde creamos una lista con un solo elemento y lo
   multiplicamos por la cantidad de elementos de nuestra lista de
   origen

> ```
> ocultar = lambda lista : ['*'] * len(lista)
>
> print('E=',ocultar(E))
> ```

### Borrar dos elementos cuando son iguales

Normalmente lo que se hace es hacer una serie de bloques `if` en función de lo que ingreso el usuario, por ejemplo algo así:

```
if Cordenadas1 = 'E' and Coordenadas3 = 'C':
   if E[int(Coordenadas2) == C[int(Coordenadas4)]:
      print("los elemento de E y C son iguales")
```

El problema que tiene esto es que hay escribir varios `if` preguntando cada una de las combinaciones. Para evitarlo y hacer más simple el código podemos hacer uso de unas técnicas muy interesantes.

En primer lugar creamos un diccionario para relacionar el caracter que eventualmente ingrese el usuario con la lista en particular:

```
listas = {'E': E, 'C': C, 'D': D, 'T': T}
```

Lo siguiente es convertir a enteros las posiciones ingresadas ya que el input es una cadena y para acceder a las listas necesitamos el índice.

```
pos1 = int(Coordenadas2)
pos2 = int(Coordenadas4)
```

Y por último, acá esta lo interesante, mediante el diccionario "mapeamos" las listas con el dato ingresado por el usuario de forma rápida, y mediante las variables `pos1`y `pos2` al ítem particular de cada lista.

```
if listas[Coordenadas1][pos1] == listas[Coordenadas3][pos2]:
  (listas[Coordenadas1]).remove(listas[Coordenadas1][pos1])
  (listas[Coordenadas3]).remove(listas[Coordenadas3][pos2])
```

Por último, como sabemos que la lista no tiene valores repetidos podemos usar `remove(valor)` para eliminar el valor elegido de cada lista.

**Importante**: Esta solución asume que el usuario ingresa valores válidos, en realidad debieras validar previamente que como lista ingrese el nombre de las mismas y no otra cosa, y como posición no se ingrese otra cosa que un numérico entre 0 y la longitud de la lista menos 1.